# I'm having issues with HTTP and HTTPS protocols

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build, protocols

I am brand spankin' new to coding. In fact, I've learned all I know about gradle through experimentation trying to make this stuff work.
I am trying to build a .jar file from an old github file and for the past week, I've been trying in and out to get this thing to work and it always spits out errors. I am currently closer than ever to building this thing -
except there's a problem.

While I try to build my jar file, I am getting the error: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. And a lot of feedback, shown below.

```
PS J:\MC\MC2\.minecraft\mods\ElectricalAge-releases-1.12\ElectricalAge-releases-1.12> .\gradlew

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ElectricalAge-releases-1.12'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:1.2.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/undercouch/gradle-download-task/1.2/gradle-download-task-1.2.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/de/undercouch/gradle-download-task/1.2/gradle-download-task-1.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.6.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.6/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.6.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.6/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.6.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.1-2.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.0.1-2/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.0.1-2.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.0.1-2/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.0.1-2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve net.md-5:SpecialSource:1.7.3.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/md-5/SpecialSource/1.7.3/SpecialSource-1.7.3.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/md-5/SpecialSource/1.7.3/SpecialSource-1.7.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/httpclient-4.3.3.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/httpclient-4.3.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.3/httpmime-4.3.3.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.3/httpmime-4.3.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.github.abrarsyed.jastyle:jAstyle:1.2.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/abrarsyed/jastyle/jAstyle/1.2/jAstyle-1.2.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/abrarsyed/jastyle/jAstyle/1.2/jAstyle-1.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve net.sf.trove4j:trove4j:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/trove4j/trove4j/2.1.0/trove4j-2.1.0.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/trove4j/trove4j/2.1.0/trove4j-2.1.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > de.oceanlabs.mcp:RetroGuard:3.6.6
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > de.oceanlabs.mcp:mcinjector:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:18.0.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.3.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.3/asm-debug-all-5.0.3.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.3/asm-debug-all-5.0.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.github.tony19:named-regexp:0.2.3.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tony19/named-regexp/0.2.3/named-regexp-0.2.3.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/tony19/named-regexp/0.2.3/named-regexp-0.2.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.cloudbees:diff4j:1.1.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/cloudbees/diff4j/1.1/diff4j-1.1.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/cloudbees/diff4j/1.1/diff4j-1.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.6.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > de.oceanlabs.mcp:RetroGuard:3.6.6
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > de.oceanlabs.mcp:mcinjector:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.6/jopt-simple-4.6.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.6/jopt-simple-4.6.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:jobs:3.5.300-v20130429-1813.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/jobs/3.5.300-v20130429-1813/jobs-3.5.300-v20130429-1813.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/core/jobs/3.5.300-v20130429-1813/jobs-3.5.300-v20130429-1813.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse:osgi:3.9.1-v20130814-1242.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/osgi/3.9.1-v20130814-1242/osgi-3.9.1-v20130814-1242.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/osgi/3.9.1-v20130814-1242/osgi-3.9.1-v20130814-1242.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:contenttype:3.4.200-v20130326-1255.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/contenttype/3.4.200-v20130326-1255/contenttype-3.4.200-v20130326-1255.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/core/contenttype/3.4.200-v20130326-1255/contenttype-3.4.200-v20130326-1255.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:resources:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/resources/3.2.1-R32x_v20060914/resources-3.2.1-R32x_v20060914.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/core/resources/3.2.1-R32x_v20060914/resources-3.2.1-R32x_v20060914.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:common:3.6.200-v20130402-1505.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/common/3.6.200-v20130402-1505/common-3.6.200-v20130402-1505.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/equinox/common/3.6.200-v20130402-1505/common-3.6.200-v20130402-1505.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.text:org.eclipse.text:3.5.101.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/text/org.eclipse.text/3.5.101/org.eclipse.text-3.5.101.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/text/org.eclipse.text/3.5.101/org.eclipse.text-3.5.101.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:3.2.0.201312181205-r.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/3.2.0.201312181205-r/org.eclipse.jgit-3.2.0.201312181205-r.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/3.2.0.201312181205-r/org.eclipse.jgit-3.2.0.201312181205-r.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.equinox:preferences:3.5.100-v20130422-1538.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/3.5.100-v20130422-1538/preferences-3.5.100-v20130422-1538.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/equinox/preferences/3.5.100-v20130422-1538/preferences-3.5.100-v20130422-1538.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.6.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.6/jopt-simple-4.6.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.6/jopt-simple-4.6.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.eclipse.core:runtime:3.9.0-v20130326-1255.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > net.minecraftforge.srg2source:Srg2Source:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/core/runtime/3.9.0-v20130326-1255/runtime-3.9.0-v20130326-1255.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/core/runtime/3.9.0-v20130326-1255/runtime-3.9.0-v20130326-1255.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.3.
     Required by:
         :ElectricalAge-releases-1.12:unspecified > net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT > de.oceanlabs.mcp:mcinjector:3.2-SNAPSHOT
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.3/asm-debug-all-5.0.3.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
      > Could not HEAD 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.3/asm-debug-all-5.0.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

This makes me so sad. I've come so far and get stopped because my gradle cannot access these websites as they require HTTPS protocols while my gradle is trying to access them with HTTP protocols.

I'm guessing this is because when this file was made, gradle had not yet switched over to being forced into using HTTPS. I've gone through all the settings files I could find and changed all dependencies to HTTPS links, and to no avail.

Keep in mind I'm a noob to code so you'll have to walk me through everything. Here are my file directories inside the github file.

[File directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZVmh.png)

Thanks if you can help. And also, I did not write any of these files. They were all written by the authors on github: https://github.com/Electrical-Age/ElectricalAge/tree/releases/1.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the problem is due to the very old Gradle version used in the `releases/1.12` branch of that repo.

The version of Gradle used by the `gradlew` command is determined by the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. If you edit that file and change the `distributionUrl` property to use `gradle-4.4-all.zip` (like in `develop` branch of this repo) instead of `gradle-2.0-all.zip`, you should be able to at least build the project.

Comment: Thanks. It was able to download some files. Unfortunately, it is still giving me an error.

Comment: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'J:\MC\MC2\.minecraft\mods\ElectricalAge-releases-1.12\ElectricalAge-releases-1.12\gradle.properties' line: 4

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not get unknown property 'https' for root project 'ElectricalAge-releases-1.12' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s`

Comment: Huh. It worked for me when I cloned that repo, switched to the `releases/1.12` branch, edited the wrapper properties file, and ran `./gradlew build`. Maybe there are some other changes in your local repo?

Comment: Alright, I restarted my console and refreshed the folders and got it to run until I got yet another error.
-----
Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241 contains a valid JDK installation.

Comment: @JamesAlley sounds like your JAVA_HOME is set to a JRE installation instead of a JDK installation.

Comment: Installed a different jdk version to match my jre. All worked! Thanks so much. Guess I'm great at trial and error :)

Comment: Nevermind. I located it and ran minecraft with the mod and - it didn't work. No ElectricalAge in this for me... I guess it was all for nothing :(. Thanks anyways!